# При клике по слайду, он встает на первую позицию, OWL?

Tags: owl-carousel

Как сделать такое на owl carousel?

Есть слайдер , показываете по 4 элемента. Элементов всего 20. Как сделать что бы при клике по элементу ( из 4 который в зоне видимости) он встал первым в зоне видимости, т.е сладер крутится что бы элемент был первым. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть стандартный инструмент в карусели - позиционирование по номеру слайда. Я вообще фичу делал, когда по слайду в одной карусели - позиционирование происходит в другой.

```
owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', ret, 300);
```

ret - номер слайда

Answer (score 0):

Вот отличный пример

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  items: 4,
  nav: true,
  navText: [
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>",
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>"
  ],
}).on('click', '.owl-item', function(e) {
  const carousel = $('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel');
  carousel.to(carousel.relative($(this).index()), false, true);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGGGGv?editors=1010